# RegCreateKeyEx() and GetLastError()

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi, registry

Why is it that `RegCreateKeyEx()` returns a `LONG`, instead of setting a `DWORD` error code via `SetLastError()`?

Would it be safe for me to convert its `LONG` return value to a `DWORD` and then set it as the global error code with `SetLastError()`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it that RegCreateKeyEx() returns a LONG, instead of setting a DWORD error code via SetLastError()?

Probably because the Registry API started life when Windows was still 16-bit, and at that time the `SetLastError()` / `GetLastError()` functions didn't exist. Whoever added the 32bit versions of the Registry function decided that keeping the calling style backwardly-compatible was more important than updating to use `SetLastError()`.

See Raymond Chen's awesome blog (and awesome book) [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/17/7137438.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/08/462402.aspx) for related info.

> Would it be safe for me to convert its LONG return value to a DWORD and then set it as the global error code with SetLastError()?

No reason why not. As long as you do this for every value including ERROR_SUCCESS.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it that RegCreateKeyEx() returns a LONG, instead of setting a DWORD error code via SetLastError()?

Hard to say for sure, without having been part of the development team that designed these APIs.

> Would it be safe for me to convert its LONG return value to a DWORD and then set it as the global error code with SetLastError()?

Safe, but pointless. With APIs that use `SetLastError` to return error codes, the caller must call `GetLastError` immediately after the API call returns. Otherwise there is a strong risk that any other code that is executed will call `SetLastError` and destroy the original error code.

So, given that you must immediately call `GetLastError`, your code would then look like this:

```
LONG retval = RegCreateKeyEx(...);
SetLastError((DWORD)err);
DWORD err := GetLastError();
```

This is somewhat pointless. You should instead write:

```
DWORD err := (DWORD)RegCreateKeyEx(...);
```

Comment: Not necessarily pointless - I've had to do exactly this once before. Say you have a long sequence of API calls to make, and failure of each one drops out to a common error-logging routine, it is neater if the error logger can retrieve the error code in the same way for all Win32 APIs. There is no risk of something else overwriting the error code in this case.

Comment: @snowcrash09 In that case though I'd just have two ways to call the logger. One passes the error code, and one does not. The variant that does not pass the error code calls `GetLastError`, and then hands off to the other variant. That way you have a uniform coding, and also avoid the SetLastError/GetLastError round trip to find out what you already knew.